# How to binding common property in multi ViewModels?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a problem with binding a common property which should be used in multi ViewModels.

In my first MainViewModel I'm connecting to database which returning list of peoples.

```
private async void Connected()
{
    try
    {
        base.Peoples = await DatabaseConnection.GetAllPersonsCommandAsync();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**In second View** I want to display these data, by binding it to Peoples:

```
<ListView Width="200" 
   Margin="0 20 0 0" 
   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding Peoples}"
   cm:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged] = [Action Peoples_SelectionChanged($source)];">
```

I'm binding `Peoples` to my `ViewModelBase`:

```
private List<Person> _peoples;
public List<Person> Peoples
{
    get => _peoples;
    set => OnPropertyChanged(ref _peoples, value);
}
```

I want to use this list of `Peoples` in other ViewModel which inherit by ViewModelBase(like MainViewModel).

I hope the question is understandable for you.

Greetings

====
Update.

This is my OnPropertyChanged method:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged<T>(ref T property, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
    {
        property = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,  new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

**=====
second update**

I tested something, and when I created new Person like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<Person> _peoples = new ObservableCollection<Person>{
    new Person("aa", "aa", 1, 1)
};
public ObservableCollection<Person> Peoples
{
    get => _peoples;
    set => OnPropertyChanged(ref _peoples, value);
}
```

I can see them. Any sulutions?

Comment: And where is your problem? What is not working as expected? What have you tried so far?

Comment: It is not working. I am getting data from `DatabaseConnection.GetAllPersonsCommandAsync();` , but there are no changes in my view.

Comment: Show us the code in the OnPropertChanged() Method.  Does it actually raise the PropertyChanged event?

Comment: Also, have you made sure to set the DataContext for the user control?

Comment: wait, I will update main post

Comment: Can you try removing the [CallerMemberName] attribute and instead pass the name of the property with nameof(Peoples)

Comment: How do you set the DataContext of the first view and how do you set the DataContext of the second view?

Comment: @Stephen Wilson it is not working. Everyting behaves this same.

Comment: @mm8 in both cases in xaml. But MainView is MetroWindow, second ViewModel is UserControl. It's matter? Like this:
    <UserControl.DataContext> 
<vm:xxxxViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

Comment: Where are you calling the Connected() method?

Answer (score 1):

Please use an `ObservableCollection<Person>` to populate changes. Also don't reinitialize it - instead use `Clear()` and `Add()`. You will also have an `CollectionChanged` event now you can use with this.

If this isn't working - please try to check if your `DataContext` is right.

Please go like this:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Peoples
    {
        get;
    }

    public MyConstructor()
    {
        Peoples = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    }

    public void RefreshPeopleCollection(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
    {
        Peoples.Clear();

        foreach(var person in persons)
        {
            Peoples.Add(person);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is good advice but I'm not sure it's the answer to his problem.  Setting a List<Person> should work fine in this example.  He might not see updates but should see the initial list.

Comment: Idk what his `AttachedProperty` is doing, but going with `List<T>` and reinitializing it -  allways feels wrong in `XAML`.

Comment: @striker use it anyway mate

Comment: Maybe go with `DataContextChanged` debug through it - if i have set the right `DataContext`.

Comment: I agree like I said but it's not the answer to his problem.

Comment: Can you add some default values to it and check if you see anything?

Comment: @Peter yea, check my main post

Comment: Can you please stop reinitializing the collection.

Comment: If this this still not working - please post your `AttachedProperty`.